# Create a Promise<Map<T,U>> from several Promise<U>

Tags: typescript, promise

I am trying to get the bills for a number of customers, using typescript:

I have a Server class, handling the queries to the server, and providing a `getBills` class, which returns a `Promise<Bill[]>`:

```
class Server {
    constructor(hostname?: string) {
        hostname = hostname || "";

    }

    getBills(customer: Customer): Promise<Datapoint[]> {
        const apiEndPoint = new URL("/API/Bills");
        let parameters = { customer: customer.name};

        //Fetch official doc
        //https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/56
        Object.keys(parameters).forEach(key => apiEndPoint.searchParams.append(key, parameters[key]));

        return fetch(apiEndPoint.toString())
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(response.statusText)
                } 
                return response.json()
            })
    }    
}
```

I would like to query the bills for several customers, and return a Map for further processing (and to keep it all async, a `Promise<Map<Customer, Bill[]>>`, but I am struggling with this step.

What I have so far:

```
getBills(): Promise<Map<Customer, Bill[]>> {
        let server = this.context.server;
        let resultMap = new Map<Customer, Bill[]>();

        let promises = [];

        for (let customer of this.customers) {
            promises.push(
                server.getBills(customer).then(result => resultMap.set(customer, result))
            );
        }
        Promise.all(promises).then(return resultMap);
    }
```

But it does not compile, since it is trying to return the map itself, and not a Promise.

I have tried to use

```
 Promise.all(promises).then(return Promise.resolve(resultMap));
```

but is does not work either.

Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a syntax error to write:

> ```
> .then(return resultMap);
> ```

The `then` method must receive a function as argument, while `return` is just a statement, not a function. So change to:

```
.then(() => resultMap);
```

Answer (score 1):

@trincot already explained the syntax error, but instead of just writing `return Promise.all(promises).then(() => { return resultMap; });` I would suggest not constructing the `Map` until you have all the results:

```
getBills(): Promise<Map<Customer, Bill[]>> {
    const server = this.context.server;
    const promises = this.customers.map(customer => 
        server.getBills(customer).then(bills => [customer, bills])
    );
    return Promise.all(promises).then(tuples => new Map(tuples));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I have trouble getting it to work. Indeed, as is, `promises` is a nested array, with type `Promise<(Customer | Bill[])[]>[]`
I guess I would need to flatten this array, but doing this while keeping type safety seems more tedious than doing nothing :)

Comment: @Maxime the type interference can't know, but what I meant was `Promise<[Customer, Bill[]]>[]`. Using `Promise.all` on that gives us a `Promise<[Customer, Bill[]][]>` where we have an array of tuples (not an array of arrays of `Cumstomer`s or `Bill[]`s), which is exactly what the `Map` constructor expects.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. The solution was to explicitely type the tuple:
`const promises = this.customers.map(customer => 
        server.getBills(customer).then(bills => { return <[Customer, Bills[]]>[customer, bills]}))`